# Change the friendly URL of a web content in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6, friendly-url

I am currently using an article display page to display my web content in *Liferay 6.2*. I'm trying to figure out how to edit the path of my friendly URL after the `/-/`.

Current URL: `siteName/-/articleName`

Desired URL: `siteName/-/topicSection/articleName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about the attribute `JournalArticle.urlTitle`. The problem is, that there is no UI in Liferay, which lets you change that attribute (at least not out of the box).

You've got two options:

- If you just want to change an existing article, you can change that attribute in the database (I'd guess that the additional `/` is no problem):

  ```
  UPDATE JournalArticle 
      SET urlTitle = 'topicSection/articleName' 
      WHERE urlTitle = 'articleName'
  ```
- If you want to offer an UI for editing that attribute, you could write a hook.

Here a short summary how to write such a hook:

1. Add this lines to your `liferay-hook.xml`:

   ```
   <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
   <language-properties>Language.properties</language-properties> 
   <custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
   ```
2. Create a file `portal.properties` in the Java source directory and add this line:

   ```
   journal.article.form.update = urlTitle
   ```
3. Create a file `Language.properties` in the Java source directory and add this line:

   ```
   urlTitle = Friendly URL
   ```
4. Add a file `WEB-INF/custom_jsps/html/portlet/journal/article/urlTitle.jsp` into the web content folder:

   ```
   <%@ include file="/html/portlet/journal/init.jsp" %>
   <% JournalArticle article = (JournalArticle)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.JOURNAL_ARTICLE); %>
   <aui:model-context bean="<%= article %>" model="<%= JournalArticle.class %>" />

   <h3>Friendly URL</h3>

   <aui:input name="urlTitle" />
   ```

Comment: I can´t believe this answer hasn't any upvote or comment. It's brilliant!! Finally a well explained way of changing a web content url title. I was using the "update database" ugly mode but now I used your hook to finally being able to modify url titles. Finally I can create web contents by copying anothers or with stupid titles that I can change later and change its url title. Nobody want these things or everybody gave up and moved to liferay 7 or so???

Comment: In my case, there is 'articleId' instead of 'articleName' in URL. So, my URLs are siteName/-/post/123456 urlTitle field in JournalArticle table has an article title, not a number. What does control that number/urlTitle to be selected to display?

Comment: In this case `/post/` identifies a `FriendlyUrlMapper` which is responsible for handling the portion after the `/post/`.